# Visual Studio Code: как быстро свернуть блоки кода?

Tags: visual-studio-code, настройки

При сохранении все свёрнутые участки кода автоматически разворачиваются.

1. Есть ли сочетание клавиш, чтобы свернуть все блоки кода в файле? Искал в сочетаниях, но не нашёл.
2. Можно ли в настройках отменить авторазворачивание, как?

Answer (score 7):

> Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 Свернуть (свернуть) все блоки
> Ctrl+K Ctrl+J Развернуть (развернуть) все блоки

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл ответ на 1 вопрос. На Windows сочетание для свёртки блоков кода:

**(Ctrl + K) + (Ctrl + 0)** (во второй части не буква O, а ноль)

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что там оно не одно. Есть разные сочетания, например для всего кода или в зависимости от уровня вложенности. Советую настроить под себя. `(Ctrl+K) + (Ctrl+0)` - довольно неудобно для регулярного использования (если вы конечно не с вима перешли) :D

Answer (score 2):

По первому вопросу - введите в поиске сочетаний клавиш "fold".

По второму - ничего подобного! Для Атома мне приходилось устанавливать специальный плагин, но VSCode из коробки оставляет все свёрнутые блоки сврнутыми и при сохранении, и даже если его перезагрузить. Единственая проблема в том, что когда используешь поиск, он развернёт все блоки, где присутствует искомый текст, но тут наверно ничего не поделать, разве что самому плагин писать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут все шорткаты, вы можете посмотреть не только как сложжить, но и как потом развернуть
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Answer (score 0):

По 1-ому вопросу:

Я использую для свертывания/развертывания всего кода:
Ctrl+Shift+NumPad_Subtract/Ctrl+Shift+NumPad_Add.

Для свертывания/развертывания участка кода:
Ctrl+NumPad_Subtract/Ctrl+NumPad_Add.

Чтобы добраться до настроек, жмем мышкой "Параметры" - "Сочетания клавиш", далее поиск по строкам "Свернуть", "Свернуть все" и "Развернуть", "Развернуть все".

По 2-ому вопросу, тоже интересно.